# The cloud-init yaml file is not valid due to dynamic variable

Tags: yaml, cloud-init

I'm getting an error with my cloud-init yaml content.
The command I execute is:

```
cloud-init devel schema --config-file test.yaml
```

And here's the test.yaml file.

```
#cloud-config
---
users:
  - default
runcmd:
  - [ TOKEN=$(echo "Htkdi_8js") ]
  - [ wget, -O, /tmp/some.sh, "https://some_public_website", --header="Authorization: Token $TOKEN" ]
```

The error is

```
Cloud config schema errors: runcmd.1: ['wget', '-O', '/tmp/some.sh', 'https://some_public_website', {'--header="Authorization': 'Token $TOKEN"'}] is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

I'm new to cloud-init. Thank you.

Comment: You could also use strings for runcmd entries instead of comma-separated lists.

Comment: Oh that will be better. That means, I would put the whole unix command and its parameters surrounded by single quote?

Comment: Got it working. I had to wrap it with single quote since I had a colon symbol in my parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a YAML flow sequences (`[…]`), an item is allowed to be either a single node, or a key-value pair. For example, in this YAML:

```yaml
[a, b: c]
```

`a` is a single node and `b: c` is a key-value pair. The semantics of this is equivalent to

```yaml
[a, {b: c}]
```

i.e. the key-value pair is a shorthand for a mapping with a single entry.

Your problem is that you give the following item in a flow sequence:

```yaml
--header="Authorization: Token $TOKEN"
```

This is parsed by YAML as a key `--header="Authorization` with a value `Token $TOKEN"`, which is not what you want. You can see this in the error output.

While YAML does support quotation, for quotes to be recognized as syntactic YAML structure, the *first* character of an item must be a quote. In your case, this is not the case and therefore the content is processed as plain scalar, where inner quotation marks are just processed as content, which is what happens in your case.

The most obvious remedy to this problem is to use single quotes:

```yaml
  - [ wget, -O, /tmp/some.sh, "https://some_public_website", '--header="Authorization: Token $TOKEN"' ]
```

With those, the item is processed as single quoted scalar, with the `:` being processed as part of the content since it is inside YAML-processed quotes.

Comment: Ah, I honestly thought that the cloud-config parser will concatenate every item from the list. I wasn't aware it was being parsed like how you explained. Thank you so much for pointing out the error I made. The examples you showed gave me a clear understanding of how it's parsed.